# Count days to end of month

Tags: swift, date

I want to count the days to the end of a month. For example if a month has 30 days and I am on day 25 I want to receive 5 as the answer. Is that possible?

Comment: Use the APIs `range(of:in:for:)` and `component(_:from:)` of `Calendar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments by vadian you can get the range of days in month for the date, get the upper bound, subtract one and then subtract the current day:

```
extension Date {
    var lastDayOfMonth: Int { Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self)!.count }
    var day: Int { Calendar.current.component(.day, from:  self) }
    var daysToEndMonth: Int { lastDayOfMonth - day }
}
```

---

```
Date().daysToEndMonth  // 10
```

Comment: Nice solution, but one part bugs me. The range returned by `Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self)` for October is 1..<32, a half-open range that excludes 32. Why doesn't it return a closed range `1...31`? Worse, `(1..<32).upperBound` returns 32 even though 32 is not part of the range, and ``(1...32).upperBound` **also** returns 32, and in that case the closed range DOES contain the upperBound. That forces you to use upperBound-1, which is quite counter-intuitive.

Comment: @DuncanC the docs are pretty clear about it **Range
A half-open interval from a lower bound up to, but not including, an upper bound.** and **ClosedRange
An interval from a lower bound up to, and including, an upper bound.** Regarding the question about  why not a closed range, the design team did choose to use Range instead of ClosedRange for all collection indices. Thats probably the main reason. Regarding the minus one you can just use the range count instead